# How to serialize a class to a JSON string in C# to use in the Properties App dictionary in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to save the state of some labels on an Xamarin.Forms App. I am following the steps of [Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/) book, it shows how to store value per value but recommends this for when you have several info:

> An application with many more items might want to consolidate them in a class named AppSettings (for example), serialize that class to an XML or a JSON string, and then save the string in the dictionary.

I am lost about how to do it, I created a simple class

```
class AppSettings
{
    public double? gain = null;
    public string mainTitle = "my title";
}
```

In my constructor I recover the properties in this way

```
      //! Recover appSettings if some

        IDictionary<string, object> properties = Application.Current.Properties;
        if (properties.ContainsKey("mainTitle"))
        {
            mainTitle.Text = properties["mainTitle"] as string;
        }

        //! New code for loading previous keypad text.
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        mainTitle.Text = app.MainTitle;
```

And the event that I use to save it is:

```
void onHomeOptionButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            Button buttonClicked = (Button)sender;

            mainTitle.Text =  buttonClicked.Text;
            // !Save keypad text.
            App app = Application.Current as App;
            app.MainTitle = mainTitle.Text;
        }
```

What I do not know is how to structure my Class so it can be serialized to JSON (**I also do not know how to do this serialization**)

I wanted to create a class in C# with this Javascript's idea:

```
myAppSettings = {
    HomePage : {
        name1 : "value1",
        name2 : "value2"
        name3 : {
            name3.name1 : "value3.1"
        }
    },
    OtherPage:{
        name1 : "value1",
        name2 : "value2"
    },
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Which is the correct way to do it in C#?

Comment: Do you mean a javascript `object` or a  `prototype` ? - because the C# equivalent of a javascript `object` is indeed a C# `object` (instance of a `class`), and the equivalent (with some significant differences) of a javascript `prototype` is a C# `class`,

Comment: Sorry, I re did the hole question as per mods recommendations..

Comment: @distante Now your question is good. All you need is to put all your setting values to a class and then serialize it as `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourSetting)`. See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: If all you are concerned with is being able to serialize an instance of a C# class to a json string, then I believe the json serializer/deserializer in json.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) will do that for any C# object.

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655327/how-can-i-save-some-user-data-locally-on-my-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: @L.B that is one part, the other one is how to correctly structure this type of class. Thanks!

Comment: @distante any class can work. Just use a class that is suitable for your needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are concerned with is being able to serialize an instance of a C# class to a json string, then I believe the json serializer/deserializer in [json.Net](http://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)  will do that for any C# object.

Comment: I do not quite understand, is Json.net open source or it costs? I am not working yet with C#/Xamarin but I am learning it, but I would like to not depend of a expensive extension ($599) **Edit** I saw, it has an MIT licence and the $599 are for support.

Comment: Json.NET is open source under the MIT license and is free for commercial use.