# How can I store lists in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to store lists natively using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: store the List as JSON in a string

Comment: hi @SushiHangover any sample for this

Comment: See the newtonsoft update section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110986/4984832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In settings Plugin you can store in a key-value fashion, so you can not directly store lists. A workaround can be, you can serialize your list into a json string, and you can store that using a key.
And when you need the list back, you can get that json string using the key and deserialize it to the original format.

Answer (score 13):

The Xamarin Settings plugin is obsolete and no longer maintained. Its functionality has been rolled into Xamarin.Essentials which is recommended going forward.

1. Add the [Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) & the [Xamarin.Essentials NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/)
2. Utilize `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to serialize/deserialize the `List<T>` to/from a `string` and save/retrieve it using `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences`

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    static class Preferences
    {
        public static List<string> SavedList
        {
            get
            {
                var savedList = Deserialize<List<string>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), null));
                return savedList ?? new List<string>();
            }
            set
            {
                var serializedList = Serialize(value);
                Preferences.Set(nameof(SavedList), serializedList);
            }
        }

        static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObject) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);

        static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

3. Reference `Preferences.SavedList` from anywhere in your code

```
void AddToList(string text)
{
    var savedList = new List<string>(Preferences.SavedList);

    savedList.Add(text);

    Preferences.SavedList = savedList;
}
```