# How can I keep the state of a timer in a Listview in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a listview where users insert their task for the day, after the task is created the is a timer in each task that keeps track of how long the user has been doing the task. The timer runs well, my issue is keeping the state of the timer of each task when the user navigates to other pages or when they logoff the app.[image]

Comment: Just store the start date somewhere (hint use UTC format)

Comment: Where should I store the start date?

Comment: Maybe this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655327/how-can-i-save-some-user-data-locally-on-my-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: So should I store the start date of each item in the list?

Comment: if each item has a different start time, then yes